# URL rewriting - work only with digit

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I'm actually working on a job for school and I try to create a URL rewriting with .htaccess.

So this is my code in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule profile/([0-9]+) profile/index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule profile/([a-zA-Z]+) profile/index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I try to create a rewriting with the ID or the Username, if I delete the last line, my code work for digit but if with the username that never works. I'm not quite good with url rewriting, learning for the moment. But is it possible to do this or not??

And if it's possible how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule profile/([0-9]+)$ profile/index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule profile/([a-zA-Z]+)$ profile/index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

You forgot the $.

Comment: Don't you also need to have a preceding '^'? Or have I been wasting one character per rule for years?
edit: thats a caret, by the way :]

Comment: I actually don't know what this is used for, but I am sure that it work's without it (also tested it right now)

Comment: @orourkek Only if you want to match the start of the URI. If you leave it off, the match is greedy. The $ matches the end of the URI.

Comment: @Matthew Well that makes sense. Currently matching the start of the uri is somewhat important for me/us, as we have many uris that point to the same filesystem. If your schema is similar, this is something you might want to watch out for